# Why does wpdb->update delete other meta?

Tags: wpdb

My existing data in the termmeta table:

| meta_id | term_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27374 | 546 | 1C_id | 9095b4cf-969d-11e9-a601-5cf3706390c8 |
| 27918 | 546 | tax_position | 1 |

My code:

```
$found_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}termmeta` WHERE meta_value='{$group['1C_id']}'");

if(!empty($found_id)) $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix.'termmeta', array('meta_key' => '1C_id', 'meta_value' => $group['1C_id']), array('term_id'=>$found_id));
```

This deletes the tax_position meta and duplicates the 1C_id meta row, can't figure out why. No other piece of my code deals with this meta field.

Comment: I'd try [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/) instead if you haven't already. But I can't see what's wrong with that at first glance though.

Comment: I'd also try the Query Monitor plugin to see what SQL WordPress is running for that update, and why it's going wrong. But I'd guess something else is doing it, not this code.

Comment: I don't use update_term_meta because I deal with terms in bulk, and with WPDB I can turn autocommit off;

Comment: I wrote my own query, and it still duplicates my meta:

$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}termmeta (term_id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES('{$check_term_name}','1C_id','{$group['1C_id']}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = '{$group['1C_id']}'");

Comment: Hold on. I guess what I need in the first place is a unique term_id+meta_key key, right?

Comment: Still have no idea how the update method erased other term meta

Comment: What are you trying to do with this query ( and why didn't you ask how to do that instead of how to fix your solution? ), this looks like an X Y Problem. Querying the core tables directly with SQL is almost always an anti-pattern and a mistake. Any context you can provide for what it's supposed to do and why you're using SQL instead of the API would be helpful

Comment: E.g. why raw SQL instead of `WP_Term_Query` and `update_term_meta`?

Comment: Hey Tom. I am dealing with tens of thousands of items and 100s of terms being imported from a program via HTTP requests. What I achieved with WPDB is a minimal number or mysql requests. As for this query, the program has internal ids for item groups. This _example_ code rewrites such id if it has been recorded before. This means it should have changed nothing, but it did rewrite other meta. I ended up replacing wpdb->update with a mysql query and adding a unique index to term meta table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UPDATE command would look like so after all variables are substituted — and in this example, the table prefix is `wp_` (the default one), `$group['1C_id']` is `9095b4cf-969d-11e9-a601-5cf3706390c8`, and `$found_id` (the term ID) is `123`.

```sql
UPDATE `wp_termmeta`
SET `meta_key` = '1C_id', `meta_value` = '9095b4cf-969d-11e9-a601-5cf3706390c8'
WHERE `term_id` = 123
```

So that means, **all** existing meta *where the term ID is `123`* and *regardless what the meta key is*, will be changed:

- First, the meta key is set to `1C_id`, so the `tax_position` meta was renamed to `1C_id`.
- Secondly, the meta value is set to `9095b4cf-969d-11e9-a601-5cf3706390c8`, which became the `tax_position`'s new value.

So that explains this: "*This deletes the tax_position meta and duplicates the 1C_id meta row*".

I.e. The `tax_position` meta was not deleted, but only its *key and value* that were changed, and that they're set to the same ones for the existing `1C_id` meta.

Therefore, `$wpdb->update()` did not actually delete or add any metadata. It's your query which isn't done correctly.

So maybe you're trying to do something like this?

*Note that I used [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare the query for safe execution, and you should do the same.*

```php
// Select meta IDs by meta value.
$meta_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT meta_id FROM $wpdb->termmeta
    WHERE meta_value = %s
", $group['1C_id'] ) );

// Then update all the above meta by the meta ID.
if ( ! empty( $meta_ids ) ) {
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
        UPDATE $wpdb->termmeta
        SET meta_key = '1C_id', meta_value = %s
        WHERE meta_id IN (" . implode( ',', $meta_ids ) . ")
    ", $group['1C_id'] ) );

    /* Or you can use update_metadata_by_mid():
    foreach ( $meta_ids as $meta_id ) {
        update_metadata_by_mid( 'term', $meta_id, $group['1C_id'], '1C_id' );
    }
    */
}
```

But then, why are you UPDATE-ing the meta value with the same value (`$group['1C_id']`) used when SELECT-ing the meta? Was that a typo? (Maybe you just wanted to update the meta key..?)

Comment: Sally, you're my angel. Reading all your answers is on my to-do list.
I can see I misused the $wpdb->update(), like the 1st key-value pair was a WHERE clause, and didn't notice my meta_id wasn't changing.

Comment: As for your question, I tried to make my example as simple as possible, so that, when I saw any changes in my table, I'd know something's wrong. My actual code finds the term _by name_, and then, if the 1C_id is different, decides what to do according to site options: replace its 1C_id with the current one or create a new term with the same name

Comment: I see. But actually, I also wanted to suggest you to use the term meta API (except maybe for selecting the meta IDs), and you could setup a cron (or background) job to process the bulk term updates, and there's also the [`wp term meta` command in WP-CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/term/meta/) which I believe could help you (see https://kinsta.com/blog/wp-cli/#using-bash-scripts). Anyway, thanks for the upvotes :)

Comment: Sally, thank you for your advice. In my current project I achieved good results using wpdb, as opposed to wp APIs. It takes only a few MYSQL requests to import tens of thousands of items, each one with multiple images, and hundreds of terms. The program I deal with sends me an xml file over http, I convert it into a temp DB (with a php generator), then use single requests to deal with all items in bulk (like 10 requests total), it gives me very reasonable server loads and my php script never runs out of memory and time.

Comment: Like so (takes 1C_groups meta, finds corresponding terms, assigns term to item, however many items there are): $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships(object_id, term_taxonomy_id) SELECT t1.ID, t3.term_id FROM wp_posts as t1 LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.post_id INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}termmeta AS t3 ON t3.meta_value = t2.meta_value WHERE t2.meta_key='1C_groups' AND t3.meta_key='1C_id' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE term_taxonomy_id=t3.term_id ");

Comment: +Will look into WP-CLI, thanks

Comment: I understand and yes, raw SQL are generally fast(er). I was just saying where possible, give a priority to using the existing PHP/WordPress APIs, and tools where available and applicable (so that for example, plugins can run their specific actions when a term is updated/added/deleted). And remember to always clean the input before saving it into the database. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you Sally. Great point on plugin actions. DB input, wilco. )

Comment: Sally, I need someone to do a little paid job for me, to write a correct wp query for my code. Could you by any chance help me with that?

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I'm not taking paid jobs for now. So if you could, post a new question and I might be able to at least post a comment. :)